# release mac app without developer license

Tags: ios, macos

i'm about to release a mac app/ ios app combo.
ie - an ios app that talks to a mac app.
I'm already part of the ios developer program, but dont want to pay another $99 for the mac developer program.
Since my mac app is free, I've read that I dont really need to sign up for the mac developer program. I can just have users download it from elsewhere.

My question is...
**Are the ios review people going to have a problem downloading my mac app if it's not in the mac app store?** (they'll need my mac app to test and review my ios app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, that's fine. It's not in the rules and I've seen several applications in the past which required a Mac app which wasn't available on the app store (for example, apps that can't be sandboxed, etc).